# Отличие Singleton и Monostate

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, singleton

хотелось бы понять разницу между паттернами Singleton и Monostate

На данный момент понял только то, что это почти одно и то же, но полноценного ответа нигде нет, везде говориться о "синтаксическом сахаре"

Хотелось бы какую-нибудь самую простую реализацию для сравнения

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/887317/312041

Comment: Если вы используете синглтон, то у вас есть **один объект** данного класса, которым вы пользуетесь в разных местах программы. Если вы используете моностейт, то у вас **несколько** объектов (которые вы создаёте как обычно, там где они нужны), но все эти объекты используют одни и те же статические (`static`) переменные у себя под капотом. Набор этих статических переменных и является состоянием, которое разделяют все объекты.